# Appending Data to a <div> tag with .NET

Tags: c#, jquery, .net, html, append

So i have the following situation in my html file:

```
<div id = "imagePreview">
    <div id = "earlyDetectionPlots">
        <div id = "earlyDetectionScoreMetricsPlots">
        </div>
        <div id = "earlyDetectionVariableMetricsPlots">
        </div>
        <div id = "earlyDetectionPseudoStandardizedCoefficientPlots">
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

I have a jQuery function as follows:

```
        $(document).on('click', 'a[data-link]', function () {
        var $this = $(this);
        url = $this.data('link');
        $("#imagePreview").load("imageProcess.aspx?" + url);
    });
```

where url has `GET` parameters in the form of something like `m=2k01&type=EarlyDetection` etc.

In my `imageProcess.aspx` file, I'm using regular expressions to grab a bunch of images from a folder.

However, each of the divs above are going to have different data in them.  I know how to decide which images go where, but I don't know how to use c# to say something like `#earlyDetectionScoreMetricsPlots.append("image.png"),` since I don't want to append the images directly to imagePreview but rather to the `sub` div within it, and as far as I know, I can't use jQuery within the `imageProcess` file.

(I think there might be a way to call specific functions within the `imageProcess.aspx` file corresponding to the different `<divs>`, but I don't know how to do that with jQuery).  Any help would be much appreciated.

Comment: Am I correct to understand that the imageprocess file returns the html markup for images that need to be positioned within various divs? or does it return actual images?

Comment: the image process file returns the html markup.  I would have done this all in jQuery but I needed to iterate through a folder.

Comment: Is your actual question how to do a directory listing in C# then?

Comment: No, i know how to do the actual iteration, and I have all the files I need; I just don't know how to assign files to be appended to a particular <div>

Comment: Can we see some sample output of `imageProcess.aspx`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You either need more complex jQuery or return the actual content you want in `#imagePreview` from `imageProcess.aspx`

Comment: So you're saying that I should create the markup for the <div> tags within the 'imageProcess.aspx' file?

Comment: Either that or you have to do create them with jQuery after returning some structured data (JSON perhaps) from `imageProcess.aspx`

Comment: how do I return JSON structured data in that case?

Comment: That's a much bigger topic, a simple answer would be to use [JSON.Net](http://json.codeplex.com/)